# Why is this SVG so blurry?

Tags: html, svg, blurry

I have a problem with my SVG:

https://codepen.io/yokogfx/pen/LzaOGp

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" role="img" fill="#fff" aria-label="Test" viewBox="0 0 348.081 96.151" width="148" height="45" version="1.1"><title>Test</title><desc>Test</desc><path class="a" d="M 6.42 95.06 a 3.72 3.72 0 0 1 -2.74 1 H 0 v -11 h 3.68 a 3.72 3.72 0 0 1 2.74 1 c 1.11 1.11 1.06 2.85 1.06 4.33 s 0.05 3.56 -1.06 4.67 Z m -0.59 -8.38 a 3.09 3.09 0 0 0 -2.35 -0.85 H 0.83 v 9.48 h 2.65 a 3.09 3.09 0 0 0 2.35 -0.85 c 0.86 -0.91 0.82 -2.82 0.82 -4 s 0.05 -2.87 -0.82 -3.78 Z M 12.75 85.1 h 0.83 v 11 h -0.83 Z M 19.28 85.1 h 6.65 v 0.74 h -5.82 v 4.33 h 5 v 0.74 h -5 v 4.42 h 5.82 v 0.74 h -6.65 Z M 37.86 86.53 v 9.53 H 37 v -11 h 0.83 l 6.33 9.5 V 85.1 H 45 v 11 h -0.83 Z M 50.71 85.1 h 6.65 v 0.74 h -5.81 v 4.33 h 5 v 0.74 h -5 v 4.42 h 5.82 v 0.74 h -6.66 Z M 65.83 96.15 a 3.55 3.55 0 0 1 -3.76 -3.65 v -7.4 h 0.83 v 7.3 a 2.93 2.93 0 1 0 5.85 0 v -7.3 h 0.83 v 7.4 a 3.55 3.55 0 0 1 -3.75 3.65 Z M 75.13 85.1 h 6.65 v 0.74 H 76 v 4.33 h 5 v 0.74 h -5 v 4.42 h 5.82 v 0.74 h -6.69 Z M 99.3 95.06 a 3.72 3.72 0 0 1 -2.74 1 h -3.68 v -11 h 3.68 a 3.72 3.72 0 0 1 2.74 1 c 1.11 1.11 1.06 2.85 1.06 4.33 s 0.05 3.56 -1.06 4.67 Z m -0.59 -8.38 a 3.09 3.09 0 0 0 -2.36 -0.85 h -2.63 v 9.48 h 2.65 a 3.09 3.09 0 0 0 2.36 -0.85 c 0.86 -0.91 0.82 -2.82 0.82 -4 s 0.03 -2.87 -0.83 -3.78 Z M 105.63 85.1 h 6.65 v 0.74 h -5.82 v 4.33 h 5 v 0.74 h -5 v 4.42 h 5.82 v 0.74 h -6.65 Z M 118 90.35 h 5 v 0.74 h -5 v 5 h -0.83 v -11 h 6.65 v 0.74 H 118 Z M 128.33 85.1 h 0.83 v 11 h -0.83 Z M 135.68 86.53 v 9.53 h -0.83 v -11 h 0.83 L 142 94.6 v -9.5 h 0.83 v 11 H 142 Z M 148.54 85.1 h 0.83 v 11 h -0.83 Z M 157.93 96.06 h -0.83 V 85.84 h -3.26 v -0.74 h 7.37 v 0.74 h -3.28 Z M 165.68 85.1 h 0.83 v 11 h -0.83 Z M 178.27 95 a 3.9 3.9 0 0 1 -5.48 0 c -1 -1 -1 -2 -1 -4.45 s 0 -3.45 1 -4.45 a 3.9 3.9 0 0 1 5.48 0 c 1 1 1 2 1 4.45 s 0 3.45 -1 4.45 Z m -0.66 -8.44 a 3 3 0 0 0 -4.16 0 c -0.78 0.78 -0.85 1.65 -0.85 4 s 0.06 3.2 0.85 4 a 3 3 0 0 0 4.16 0 c 0.79 -0.78 0.85 -1.65 0.85 -4 s -0.07 -3.18 -0.85 -3.97 Z M 185.38 86.53 v 9.53 h -0.83 v -11 h 0.83 l 6.33 9.5 V 85.1 h 0.83 v 11 h -0.83 Z M 206.54 96.06 l -3.6 -11 h 0.88 l 3.08 9.5 l 3.1 -9.46 h 0.88 l -3.6 11 Z M 220.92 95 a 3.9 3.9 0 0 1 -5.48 0 c -1 -1 -1 -2 -1 -4.45 s 0 -3.45 1 -4.45 a 3.9 3.9 0 0 1 5.48 0 c 1 1 1 2 1 4.45 s 0 3.45 -1 4.45 Z m -0.66 -8.44 a 3 3 0 0 0 -4.16 0 c -0.78 0.78 -0.85 1.65 -0.85 4 s 0.06 3.2 0.85 4 a 3 3 0 0 0 4.16 0 c 0.79 -0.78 0.85 -1.65 0.85 -4 s -0.11 -3.18 -0.86 -3.97 Z M 228 86.53 v 9.53 h -0.83 v -11 h 0.83 l 6.33 9.5 V 85.1 h 0.83 v 11 h -0.83 Z M 250 96.06 h -0.83 V 85.84 h -3.26 v -0.74 h 7.37 v 0.74 H 250 Z M 262.3 93.4 h -5.11 l -1 2.66 h -0.89 l 4 -11 h 0.74 l 4 11 h -0.89 Z m -4.85 -0.74 H 262 l -2.29 -6.45 Z M 269.21 86.53 v 9.53 h -0.83 v -11 h 0.83 l 6.33 9.5 V 85.1 h 0.83 v 11 h -0.83 Z M 281.35 95.18 l 5.77 -9.34 h -5.54 v -0.74 H 288 v 0.74 l -5.82 9.48 H 288 v 0.74 h -6.67 Z M 288 45.14 c 0.22 -20.77 -19 -27.76 -32.41 -18.37 v -4.29 h -11.23 v 50.44 h 11.24 V 44.68 c 0.47 -13.65 21.16 -13.5 21.16 0.47 v 27.77 H 288 V 45.14 Z M 92.53 22.5 v 4.9 a 25.83 25.83 0 1 0 0 41.73 v 3.78 h 11.24 V 22.5 Z M 77.3 62.88 a 14.64 14.64 0 1 1 13.57 -9.21 a 14.61 14.61 0 0 1 -13.57 9.21 Z M 167.08 32.18 h 13 v -9.75 h -13 V 10.74 h -11.24 v 11.7 h -7.29 v 9.74 h 7.23 v 19 c 0 0.79 0 1.55 0.06 2.29 a 24.13 24.13 0 0 0 1.46 7.61 a 16.47 16.47 0 0 0 5 6.65 a 23.06 23.06 0 0 0 12.28 5 a 30 30 0 0 0 3.31 0.2 h 1.29 V 62.24 H 177.88 a 11.73 11.73 0 0 1 -6.88 -1.89 a 8.33 8.33 0 0 1 -3.46 -5.28 a 15.14 15.14 0 0 1 -0.44 -3 V 32.18 Z M 223 22.51 v 29.1 a 19.25 19.25 0 0 1 -0.51 5 a 8.33 8.33 0 0 1 -3.49 5.26 a 11.71 11.71 0 0 1 -6.87 1.93 h -0.05 q -5.29 0 -8.14 -3 a 7.89 7.89 0 0 1 -2.14 -3.45 a 23.1 23.1 0 0 1 -0.51 -5.69 v -29 l -11.24 -0.09 v 30.15 a 34 34 0 0 0 0.91 8.22 a 18 18 0 0 0 7.75 9.74 a 24.23 24.23 0 0 0 13.42 3.75 a 24 24 0 0 0 15.6 -5.17 a 16.47 16.47 0 0 0 5 -6.65 a 27.07 27.07 0 0 0 1.52 -9.89 V 22.51 Z M 348.07 63.87 V 22.51 h -11.24 v 4.89 a 25.84 25.84 0 1 0 0 41.73 c 0 4.4 -0.66 8.15 -3.81 11.45 a 14.26 14.26 0 0 1 -23.94 -5.69 l -10.55 3.66 A 25.42 25.42 0 0 0 345.46 82 c 2.93 -5.81 2.61 -11.84 2.61 -18.13 Z m -12.95 -10.21 a 14.45 14.45 0 1 1 1 -5.39 a 14.55 14.55 0 0 1 -1 5.39 Z M 126.49 43.13 v -0.25 c 0.06 -0.32 0.13 -0.63 0.21 -0.95 v -0.16 a 13.06 13.06 0 0 1 12.6 -9.66 c 0.42 0 0.83 0 1.23 0.06 v -9.68 h -0.33 c -5.18 0 -10.59 0.29 -14.07 4.7 v -4.75 H 115 v 50.48 h 11.2 V 47.39 a 30.78 30.78 0 0 1 0.17 -3.39 c 0.03 -0.3 0.07 -0.58 0.12 -0.87 Z M 43.72 45.14 c 0.22 -20.77 -19 -27.76 -32.41 -18.37 V 0 H 0.07 v 72.92 h 11.24 V 44.68 c 0.47 -13.65 21.16 -13.5 21.16 0.47 v 27.77 h 11.25 V 45.14 Z" /></svg>
```

Do you see that the SVG is blurry / pixelated?

Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: The SVG isn't the problem; it's your display device.

Comment: @chepner  I use an 4K Monitor, this doesnt look right :/

Comment: Are you talking about the claim line underneath the brand name? Well that is so small to begin with, that it could simply be replaced by a solid white line, without loosing legibility ...

Comment: @CBroe Yes I am talking about the claim line underneath the brand name. But if I use a PNG it isnt blurry, it has to do with the SVG.

Comment: How is the PNG generated? Can you add it for comparison? Part of the problem is that the SVG is simply a *specification*; the appearance has as much to do with the particular SVG renderer used as it does with your code.

Comment: @chepner The PNG is generated by Illustrator, I added it to the Codepen.

Comment: The SVG looks better than the PNG on my monitor (Safari 11.0, 27" iMac Retina 5k), zoomed in or out. What are you using to view the SVG?

Comment: @chepner I use Edge and Chrome. But I got another Idea wouldnt it be possible to do this little text with the <text><text> property of SVG?

Comment: Yes it is possible, but then you may run into font problems - unless you use a webfont.

Comment: When you generated the PNG from Illustrator, had the text been converted to outlines, or was it still a text object?  If the latter, then it has an advantage because it knows the pixel density and can optimise the glyph outlines. The browser can't do that with a generic path.

Comment: If you want that text to look crisp in SVG, then overlay a grid corresponding to the pixels in Illustrator and optimise the character glyph shapes to align with the grid.

Comment: @PaulLeBeau The Text in the PNG I generated was converted to outlines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want that text to look crisp, at such a small size in SVG, the best solution is to tweak the glyph shapes so that the fit within the pixel boundaries better.

The following illustration shows what I mean.  In my editor I turned on a 148x45 grid to match the output size. Then I tweaked the character shapes so that they lay within the pixel boundaries better.  The black shape is the original path shape, and the grey is the tweaked version.  I looked for parts of the glyphs that were spanning the pixel boundary, and adjusted them so that were no longer doing that.  You want to especially focus on the vertical and horizontal stems of the glyphs.

In the image below, the right hand side of the "D" is running down a grid line. I shifted that part right a little so it was wholly in the next column of pixels.  I could have moved that part left, but I didn't want the character to look too narrow.  In the case of the "N" I just shifted it a fraction leftwards.

[image]

In the updated example below, the second SVG is my modified version where I have tweaked the first "D", "N" and "F" to show the improvement.  I'll leave the rest of the tweaking to you.

```css
body {background:#000}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" role="img" fill="#fff" aria-label="Test" viewBox="0 0 348.081 96.151" width="148" height="45" version="1.1"><title>Test</title><desc>Test</desc><path class="a" d="M 6.42 95.06 a 3.72 3.72 0 0 1 -2.74 1 H 0 v -11 h 3.68 a 3.72 3.72 0 0 1 2.74 1 c 1.11 1.11 1.06 2.85 1.06 4.33 s 0.05 3.56 -1.06 4.67 Z m -0.59 -8.38 a 3.09 3.09 0 0 0 -2.35 -0.85 H 0.83 v 9.48 h 2.65 a 3.09 3.09 0 0 0 2.35 -0.85 c 0.86 -0.91 0.82 -2.82 0.82 -4 s 0.05 -2.87 -0.82 -3.78 Z M 12.75 85.1 h 0.83 v 11 h -0.83 Z M 19.28 85.1 h 6.65 v 0.74 h -5.82 v 4.33 h 5 v 0.74 h -5 v 4.42 h 5.82 v 0.74 h -6.65 Z M 37.86 86.53 v 9.53 H 37 v -11 h 0.83 l 6.33 9.5 V 85.1 H 45 v 11 h -0.83 Z M 50.71 85.1 h 6.65 v 0.74 h -5.81 v 4.33 h 5 v 0.74 h -5 v 4.42 h 5.82 v 0.74 h -6.66 Z M 65.83 96.15 a 3.55 3.55 0 0 1 -3.76 -3.65 v -7.4 h 0.83 v 7.3 a 2.93 2.93 0 1 0 5.85 0 v -7.3 h 0.83 v 7.4 a 3.55 3.55 0 0 1 -3.75 3.65 Z M 75.13 85.1 h 6.65 v 0.74 H 76 v 4.33 h 5 v 0.74 h -5 v 4.42 h 5.82 v 0.74 h -6.69 Z M 99.3 95.06 a 3.72 3.72 0 0 1 -2.74 1 h -3.68 v -11 h 3.68 a 3.72 3.72 0 0 1 2.74 1 c 1.11 1.11 1.06 2.85 1.06 4.33 s 0.05 3.56 -1.06 4.67 Z m -0.59 -8.38 a 3.09 3.09 0 0 0 -2.36 -0.85 h -2.63 v 9.48 h 2.65 a 3.09 3.09 0 0 0 2.36 -0.85 c 0.86 -0.91 0.82 -2.82 0.82 -4 s 0.03 -2.87 -0.83 -3.78 Z M 105.63 85.1 h 6.65 v 0.74 h -5.82 v 4.33 h 5 v 0.74 h -5 v 4.42 h 5.82 v 0.74 h -6.65 Z M 118 90.35 h 5 v 0.74 h -5 v 5 h -0.83 v -11 h 6.65 v 0.74 H 118 Z M 128.33 85.1 h 0.83 v 11 h -0.83 Z M 135.68 86.53 v 9.53 h -0.83 v -11 h 0.83 L 142 94.6 v -9.5 h 0.83 v 11 H 142 Z M 148.54 85.1 h 0.83 v 11 h -0.83 Z M 157.93 96.06 h -0.83 V 85.84 h -3.26 v -0.74 h 7.37 v 0.74 h -3.28 Z M 165.68 85.1 h 0.83 v 11 h -0.83 Z M 178.27 95 a 3.9 3.9 0 0 1 -5.48 0 c -1 -1 -1 -2 -1 -4.45 s 0 -3.45 1 -4.45 a 3.9 3.9 0 0 1 5.48 0 c 1 1 1 2 1 4.45 s 0 3.45 -1 4.45 Z m -0.66 -8.44 a 3 3 0 0 0 -4.16 0 c -0.78 0.78 -0.85 1.65 -0.85 4 s 0.06 3.2 0.85 4 a 3 3 0 0 0 4.16 0 c 0.79 -0.78 0.85 -1.65 0.85 -4 s -0.07 -3.18 -0.85 -3.97 Z M 185.38 86.53 v 9.53 h -0.83 v -11 h 0.83 l 6.33 9.5 V 85.1 h 0.83 v 11 h -0.83 Z M 206.54 96.06 l -3.6 -11 h 0.88 l 3.08 9.5 l 3.1 -9.46 h 0.88 l -3.6 11 Z M 220.92 95 a 3.9 3.9 0 0 1 -5.48 0 c -1 -1 -1 -2 -1 -4.45 s 0 -3.45 1 -4.45 a 3.9 3.9 0 0 1 5.48 0 c 1 1 1 2 1 4.45 s 0 3.45 -1 4.45 Z m -0.66 -8.44 a 3 3 0 0 0 -4.16 0 c -0.78 0.78 -0.85 1.65 -0.85 4 s 0.06 3.2 0.85 4 a 3 3 0 0 0 4.16 0 c 0.79 -0.78 0.85 -1.65 0.85 -4 s -0.11 -3.18 -0.86 -3.97 Z M 228 86.53 v 9.53 h -0.83 v -11 h 0.83 l 6.33 9.5 V 85.1 h 0.83 v 11 h -0.83 Z M 250 96.06 h -0.83 V 85.84 h -3.26 v -0.74 h 7.37 v 0.74 H 250 Z M 262.3 93.4 h -5.11 l -1 2.66 h -0.89 l 4 -11 h 0.74 l 4 11 h -0.89 Z m -4.85 -0.74 H 262 l -2.29 -6.45 Z M 269.21 86.53 v 9.53 h -0.83 v -11 h 0.83 l 6.33 9.5 V 85.1 h 0.83 v 11 h -0.83 Z M 281.35 95.18 l 5.77 -9.34 h -5.54 v -0.74 H 288 v 0.74 l -5.82 9.48 H 288 v 0.74 h -6.67 Z M 288 45.14 c 0.22 -20.77 -19 -27.76 -32.41 -18.37 v -4.29 h -11.23 v 50.44 h 11.24 V 44.68 c 0.47 -13.65 21.16 -13.5 21.16 0.47 v 27.77 H 288 V 45.14 Z M 92.53 22.5 v 4.9 a 25.83 25.83 0 1 0 0 41.73 v 3.78 h 11.24 V 22.5 Z M 77.3 62.88 a 14.64 14.64 0 1 1 13.57 -9.21 a 14.61 14.61 0 0 1 -13.57 9.21 Z M 167.08 32.18 h 13 v -9.75 h -13 V 10.74 h -11.24 v 11.7 h -7.29 v 9.74 h 7.23 v 19 c 0 0.79 0 1.55 0.06 2.29 a 24.13 24.13 0 0 0 1.46 7.61 a 16.47 16.47 0 0 0 5 6.65 a 23.06 23.06 0 0 0 12.28 5 a 30 30 0 0 0 3.31 0.2 h 1.29 V 62.24 H 177.88 a 11.73 11.73 0 0 1 -6.88 -1.89 a 8.33 8.33 0 0 1 -3.46 -5.28 a 15.14 15.14 0 0 1 -0.44 -3 V 32.18 Z M 223 22.51 v 29.1 a 19.25 19.25 0 0 1 -0.51 5 a 8.33 8.33 0 0 1 -3.49 5.26 a 11.71 11.71 0 0 1 -6.87 1.93 h -0.05 q -5.29 0 -8.14 -3 a 7.89 7.89 0 0 1 -2.14 -3.45 a 23.1 23.1 0 0 1 -0.51 -5.69 v -29 l -11.24 -0.09 v 30.15 a 34 34 0 0 0 0.91 8.22 a 18 18 0 0 0 7.75 9.74 a 24.23 24.23 0 0 0 13.42 3.75 a 24 24 0 0 0 15.6 -5.17 a 16.47 16.47 0 0 0 5 -6.65 a 27.07 27.07 0 0 0 1.52 -9.89 V 22.51 Z M 348.07 63.87 V 22.51 h -11.24 v 4.89 a 25.84 25.84 0 1 0 0 41.73 c 0 4.4 -0.66 8.15 -3.81 11.45 a 14.26 14.26 0 0 1 -23.94 -5.69 l -10.55 3.66 A 25.42 25.42 0 0 0 345.46 82 c 2.93 -5.81 2.61 -11.84 2.61 -18.13 Z m -12.95 -10.21 a 14.45 14.45 0 1 1 1 -5.39 a 14.55 14.55 0 0 1 -1 5.39 Z M 126.49 43.13 v -0.25 c 0.06 -0.32 0.13 -0.63 0.21 -0.95 v -0.16 a 13.06 13.06 0 0 1 12.6 -9.66 c 0.42 0 0.83 0 1.23 0.06 v -9.68 h -0.33 c -5.18 0 -10.59 0.29 -14.07 4.7 v -4.75 H 115 v 50.48 h 11.2 V 47.39 a 30.78 30.78 0 0 1 0.17 -3.39 c 0.03 -0.3 0.07 -0.58 0.12 -0.87 Z M 43.72 45.14 c 0.22 -20.77 -19 -27.76 -32.41 -18.37 V 0 H 0.07 v 72.92 h 11.24 V 44.68 c 0.47 -13.65 21.16 -13.5 21.16 0.47 v 27.77 h 11.25 V 45.14 Z" /></svg>
<br>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" role="img" fill="#fff" aria-label="Test" viewBox="0 0 348.081 96.151" width="148" height="45" version="1.1"><title>Test</title><desc>Test</desc><path class="a" d="m 7.490133,95.024329 c -0.7391233,0.692428 -1.7286192,1.053558 -2.74,1 L 0,96.06 v -11 l 4.750133,-0.03567 c 1.0113808,-0.05356 2.0008767,0.307572 2.74,1 1.11,1.11 1.06,2.85 1.06,4.33 0,1.48 0.05,3.56 -1.06,4.67 z m -0.59,-8.38 c -0.6287095,-0.60158 -1.4819268,-0.91019 -2.35,-0.85 L 0.83,85.83 v 9.48 l 3.720133,-0.03567 c 0.8680732,0.06019 1.7212905,-0.24842 2.35,-0.85 0.86,-0.91 0.82,-2.82 0.82,-4 0,-1.18 0.05,-2.87 -0.82,-3.78 z M 12.75,85.1 h 0.83 v 11 h -0.83 z m 6.53,0 h 6.65 v 0.74 h -5.82 v 4.33 h 5 v 0.74 h -5 v 4.42 h 5.82 v 0.74 h -6.65 z m 18.080605,1.251644 v 9.53 h -0.86 v -11 h 0.83 l 6.33,9.5 v -9.46 h 0.84 v 11 h -0.83 z M 50.71,85.1 h 6.65 v 0.74 h -5.81 v 4.33 h 5 v 0.74 h -5 v 4.42 h 5.82 v 0.74 h -6.66 z m 15.12,11.05 c -2.082291,0.124333 -3.822469,-1.564936 -3.76,-3.65 v -7.4 h 0.83 v 7.3 c -0.241867,4.134797 6.091867,4.134797 5.85,0 v -7.3 h 0.83 v 7.4 c 0.062,2.08085 -1.671585,3.768206 -3.75,3.65 z m 9.3,-11.05 h 6.65 v 0.74 H 76 v 4.33 h 5 v 0.74 h -5 v 4.42 h 5.82 v 0.74 h -6.69 z m 24.17,9.96 c -0.739123,0.692428 -1.728619,1.053558 -2.74,1 h -3.68 v -11 h 3.68 c 1.011381,-0.05356 2.000877,0.307572 2.74,1 1.11,1.11 1.06,2.85 1.06,4.33 0,1.48 0.05,3.56 -1.06,4.67 z m -0.59,-8.38 c -0.631112,-0.604252 -1.488539,-0.913071 -2.36,-0.85 h -2.63 v 9.48 h 2.65 c 0.871461,0.06307 1.728888,-0.245748 2.36,-0.85 0.86,-0.91 0.82,-2.82 0.82,-4 0,-1.18 0.03,-2.87 -0.83,-3.78 z m 6.92,-1.58 h 6.65 v 0.74 h -5.82 v 4.33 h 5 v 0.74 h -5 v 4.42 h 5.82 v 0.74 h -6.65 z m 11.8706,5.449422 h 5 v 0.74 h -5 v 5 h -0.83 v -11 h 6.65 v 0.74 h -5.82 z M 128.33,85.1 h 0.83 v 11 h -0.83 z m 7.35,1.43 v 9.53 h -0.83 v -11 h 0.83 L 142,94.6 v -9.5 h 0.83 v 11 H 142 Z m 12.86,-1.43 h 0.83 v 11 h -0.83 z m 9.39,10.96 H 157.1 V 85.84 h -3.26 V 85.1 h 7.37 v 0.74 h -3.28 z m 7.75,-10.96 h 0.83 v 11 h -0.83 z m 12.59,9.9 c -1.5189,1.499574 -3.9611,1.499574 -5.48,0 -1,-1 -1,-2 -1,-4.45 0,-2.45 0,-3.45 1,-4.45 1.5189,-1.499574 3.9611,-1.499574 5.48,0 1,1 1,2 1,4.45 0,2.45 0,3.45 -1,4.45 z m -0.66,-8.44 c -1.16151,-1.117532 -2.99849,-1.117532 -4.16,0 -0.78,0.78 -0.85,1.65 -0.85,4 0,2.35 0.06,3.2 0.85,4 1.16151,1.117532 2.99849,1.117532 4.16,0 0.79,-0.78 0.85,-1.65 0.85,-4 0,-2.35 -0.07,-3.18 -0.85,-3.97 z m 7.77,-0.03 v 9.53 h -0.83 v -11 h 0.83 l 6.33,9.5 V 85.1 h 0.83 v 11 h -0.83 z m 21.16,9.53 -3.6,-11 h 0.88 l 3.08,9.5 3.1,-9.46 h 0.88 l -3.6,11 z M 220.92,95 c -1.5189,1.499574 -3.9611,1.499574 -5.48,0 -1,-1 -1,-2 -1,-4.45 0,-2.45 0,-3.45 1,-4.45 1.5189,-1.499574 3.9611,-1.499574 5.48,0 1,1 1,2 1,4.45 0,2.45 0,3.45 -1,4.45 z m -0.66,-8.44 c -1.16151,-1.117532 -2.99849,-1.117532 -4.16,0 -0.78,0.78 -0.85,1.65 -0.85,4 0,2.35 0.06,3.2 0.85,4 1.16151,1.117532 2.99849,1.117532 4.16,0 0.79,-0.78 0.85,-1.65 0.85,-4 0,-2.35 -0.11,-3.18 -0.86,-3.97 z M 228,86.53 v 9.53 h -0.83 v -11 H 228 l 6.33,9.5 V 85.1 h 0.83 v 11 h -0.83 z m 22,9.53 h -0.83 V 85.84 h -3.26 V 85.1 h 7.37 v 0.74 H 250 Z m 12.3,-2.66 h -5.11 l -1,2.66 h -0.89 l 4,-11 h 0.74 l 4,11 h -0.89 z m -4.85,-0.74 H 262 l -2.29,-6.45 z m 11.76,-6.13 v 9.53 h -0.83 v -11 h 0.83 l 6.33,9.5 V 85.1 h 0.83 v 11 h -0.83 z m 12.14,8.65 5.77,-9.34 h -5.54 V 85.1 H 288 v 0.74 l -5.82,9.48 H 288 v 0.74 h -6.67 z M 288,45.14 C 288.22,24.37 269,17.38 255.59,26.77 V 22.48 H 244.36 V 72.92 H 255.6 V 44.68 c 0.47,-13.65 21.16,-13.5 21.16,0.47 V 72.92 H 288 Z M 92.53,22.5 v 4.9 C 75.461286,14.944039 51.474279,27.135676 51.474279,48.265 c 0,21.129324 23.987007,33.320961 41.055721,20.865 v 3.78 h 11.24 V 22.5 Z M 77.3,62.88 C 62.861589,62.905415 57.111416,44.233361 69.053789,36.128036 80.996162,28.022711 96.225216,40.26142 90.87,53.67 88.65887,59.228708 83.282335,62.877779 77.3,62.88 Z m 89.78,-30.7 h 13 v -9.75 h -13 V 10.74 h -11.24 v 11.7 h -7.29 v 9.74 h 7.23 v 19 c 0,0.79 0,1.55 0.06,2.29 0.0735,2.598754 0.56656,5.168548 1.46,7.61 1.07009,2.608043 2.79169,4.897767 5,6.65 3.51559,2.832883 7.78545,4.571426 12.28,5 1.0988,0.127641 2.20382,0.194409 3.31,0.2 h 1.29 V 62.24 h -1.3 c -2.43395,0.09967 -4.83855,-0.560893 -6.88,-1.89 -1.80138,-1.237902 -3.04405,-3.134224 -3.46,-5.28 -0.24668,-0.982757 -0.39409,-1.987796 -0.44,-3 V 32.18 Z M 223,22.51 v 29.1 c 0.0492,1.681793 -0.12222,3.362783 -0.51,5 -0.42822,2.143294 -1.68165,4.032424 -3.49,5.26 -2.03344,1.34241 -4.43498,2.017078 -6.87,1.93 h -0.05 c -3.52667,0 -6.24,-1 -8.14,-3 -1.00205,-0.943648 -1.73981,-2.133022 -2.14,-3.45 -0.40478,-1.868258 -0.57609,-3.779537 -0.51,-5.69 v -29 l -11.24,-0.09 v 30.15 c -0.0323,2.766821 0.27331,5.527237 0.91,8.22 1.34288,4.064977 4.0906,7.518251 7.75,9.74 4.00966,2.537035 8.67598,3.840962 13.42,3.75 5.64639,0.166239 11.17047,-1.664497 15.6,-5.17 2.20831,-1.752233 3.92991,-4.041957 5,-6.65 1.11685,-3.173568 1.63232,-6.527521 1.52,-9.89 V 22.51 Z M 348.07,63.87 V 22.51 h -11.24 v 4.89 c -17.07379,-12.473542 -41.08268,-0.278788 -41.08268,20.865 0,21.143788 24.00889,33.338542 41.08268,20.865 0,4.4 -0.66,8.15 -3.81,11.45 -7.53312,7.872492 -20.75461,4.730041 -23.94,-5.69 l -10.55,3.66 c 3.19664,9.815442 12.01172,16.723049 22.3068,17.479879 C 331.13188,96.786709 340.86234,91.242454 345.46,82 c 2.93,-5.81 2.61,-11.84 2.61,-18.13 z M 335.12,53.66 c -2.72277,6.931623 -10.26807,10.658643 -17.42545,8.608835 -7.15718,-2.04975 -11.58044,-9.204291 -10.22205,-16.526006 1.35839,-7.321716 8.05368,-12.413444 15.46981,-11.759426 7.41634,0.654036 13.12257,6.839596 13.17769,14.286597 0.0112,1.843799 -0.32816,3.672925 -1,5.39 z M 126.49,43.13 v -0.25 c 0.06,-0.32 0.13,-0.63 0.21,-0.95 v -0.16 c 1.53594,-5.696373 6.70019,-9.655634 12.6,-9.66 0.42,0 0.83,0 1.23,0.06 v -9.68 h -0.33 c -5.18,0 -10.59,0.29 -14.07,4.7 V 22.44 H 115 v 50.48 h 11.2 V 47.39 c -0.006,-1.132267 0.051,-2.263987 0.17,-3.39 0.03,-0.3 0.07,-0.58 0.12,-0.87 z M 43.72,45.14 C 43.94,24.37 24.72,17.38 11.31,26.77 V 0 H 0.07 V 72.92 H 11.31 V 44.68 c 0.47,-13.65 21.16,-13.5 21.16,0.47 v 27.77 h 11.25 z" /></svg>
```

Answer (score 2):

You should separate your svg file into 2 different paths... the main logo in one path and the tagline in another. Then you can apply shape-rendering options to each path individually. If you put:

```
shape-rendering="crispEdges"
```

on the tag line, it will use less anti-aliasing and make it so the small pixels don't get blurred out. You can explore all the shape-rendering options and decide if svg will work for you in this scenario or not.

[example](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/eGXraE)

Comment: It looks better, but is it possible to do this little "slogan" with just a normal Text? Because I just tried it and it looks better but I dont know how to do it right. Do you have an Idea how to do the Slogan with normal text instead of SVG?